# Recursive IO in Haskell

Tags: haskell, recursion, io, monads, lazy-evaluation

In Haskell I can easily define a recursive function which takes a value and returns a string:

```
Prelude> let countdown i = if (i > 0) then (show i) ++ countdown (i-1) else ""
Prelude> countdown 5
"54321"
```

I want to use the same kind of design to read available data from a file handle. In this particular case I need to read the data in the same fashion as hGetContents, but without leaving the handle in the "semi-closed" state, so that I can loop interaction with stdin/stdout handles of a process opened with createProcess:

```hs
main = do
    -- do work to get hin / hout handles for subprocess input / output

    hPutStrLn hin "whats up?"

    -- works
    -- putStrLn =<< hGetContents hout

    putStrLn =<< hGetLines hout

    where
        hGetLines h = do
            readable <- hIsReadable h
            if readable
                then hGetLine h ++ hGetLines h
                else []
```

Gives the error:

```
Couldn't match expected type `IO b0' with actual type `[a0]'
In the expression: hGetLine h : hGetLines h
```

I know there are various libraries available for accomplishing what I'm trying to accomplish, but sice I'm learning my question is really how to perform recursive IO. TIA!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Naive solution, strict and *O(n)* stack**

You still have to use the *do*-notation, which would lead to this:

```
import System.IO
import System.IO.Unsafe (unsafeInterleaveIO)

-- Too strict!
hGetLines :: Handle -> IO [String]
hGetLines h = do
    readable <- hIsReadable h
    if readable
        then do
            x  <- hGetLine h
            xs <- hGetLines h
            return (x:xs)
        else return []
```

But see my comment, this version of `hGetLines` is too strict!

**Lazy, streaming version**

It won't return your list, until it has all the input. You need something a bit lazier. For this, we have `unsafeInterleaveIO`,

```
-- Just right
hGetLines' :: Handle -> IO [String]
hGetLines' h = unsafeInterleaveIO $ do
    readable <- hIsReadable h
    if readable
        then do
            x  <- hGetLine h
            xs <- hGetLines' h
            return (x:xs)
        else return []
```

Now you can start streaming results line-by-line to your consumer code:

```
*Main> hGetLines' stdin
123
["123"345
,"345"321
,"321"^D^CInterrupted.
```

Answer (score 6):

If you check the type of `(++)` in ghci you get:

```
Prelude> :t (++)
(++) :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]
```

Meaning you can only append lists together (Remember that `String` is an alias for `[Char]`, so it's a list). The type of hGetLine is `Handle -> IO String`, and the type of `hGetLines` should be `IO [String]` So you can not append these values. `(:)` has type `a -> [a]` and works better here.

```
if readable
  then do
    -- First you need to extract them
    a <- hGetLine h
    b <- hGetLines h
    -- a and b have type String
    -- Now we can cons them and then go back into IO
    return (a : b)
```

The same applies for `else []`. You need a value of type `IO [String]` to be returned. Change it to `return []`

Also, you won't be able to just `putStrLn` the lines since `(=<< hGetLines h)` gives you `[String]` and not `String` which is what `putStrLn` expects.
This can be solved in several ways. One is to concat the values first. `putStrln . concat =<< (hGetLines h)`. Or you can print each line using `mapM_ putStrLn (hGetLines h)`.

Comment: Did you mean to call `hGetLines` in the second call there?

Comment: Woops. Missed the recursive call, so `:` should be used instead.

Comment: Note that this example won't stream, and uses *O(n)* stack.

Answer (score -1):

This is saying that part of the code expects hGetLines h to have type `IO a` and another part finds it to have type `[a]`. You probably want your if statement to be:

```
if readable
    then return hGetLine h ++ hGetLines h
    else return []
```

Comment: Your code is somewhat strange... It doesn't even compile. How about this: `if readable then hGetLine >>= \a -> hGetLine >>= \b -> return $ a + b else return []`? Another problem is, that this doesn't streams.